# Nginx rewrite rules not working / being ignored

Tags: apache, .htaccess, nginx, url-rewriting

I'm currently trying to rewrite  this:

```
index.php?page=Example&paramX=1&paramY=2
```

to

```
index.php/Example/1/?paramY=2
```

However, this isn't working:

```
rewrite ^index\.php/\?page=Example&paramX=([0-9]+)&paramY=([0-9]+)$ /index.php/Example/$arg_paramX/?paramY=$arg_paramY permanent;
```

In apache2, i currently use

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} page=Example&paramX=([0-9]+)&paramY=([0-9]+)
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /index.php/Example/%1/?paramY=%2 [R=permanent,L]
```

which is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't match query string parameters like that in nginx, you've got to try to check the individual arguments using something like an `if`:

```
location /index.php {
   if ($arg_page = "Example") {
      rewrite ^ /index.php/Example/$arg_paramX/?paramY=$arg_paramY permanent;
   }
}
```

If you absolutely need to verify that `paramX` and `paramY` are `[0-9]+`, then you'll need to do some sort of hack for nested IF statements, something like [this](https://gist.github.com/jrom/1760790).

Comment: So there's no other way than several if statements for several rules?

Comment: @user2368182 not if you want to match against the query string